# AngularJS - text labels as service or inline?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a medium sized app and was wondering if I should keep all string literals in templates, or put them all into a service:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="foo.html">
    <div ng-show="deadline.start">
        <p>
            A paragraph of text // inline
        </p>
        <p>
            {{labels.FOO}}      // the same text in a service
        </p>
    </div>
</script>
```

The advantage is, as far as I understand, that you have everything in one place, and the downside is that you would create unnecessary bindings. Any advice you could give on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try angular translate.

It provides translation, it keeps all your strings in one place and you get all the angular ways of including strings in your code:

http://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: I see, so the main reason I would want to keep them in a service is when the app would be translatable. Cheers.